# How can I securely erase a hard drive?

Tags: filesystem

I'm planning on selling a USB external hard drive that currently contains an old Ubuntu installation with stored passwords and banking information.

How can I securely erase the drive before selling it?

Comment: Also, have a look at [this EFF page](https://ssd.eff.org/tech/deletion) for a comprehensive explanation covering multiple OS's.

Comment: @Lekensteyn 'Remove the keyslots'? Just searched AU and got nothing but [this partially related](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102271/full-disk-encryption-vulnerabilities) Q&A. Should I ask this as a new question or is it covered here?

Comment: If you've a secure passphrase, the world is not lost when you lose your drive. However, it's recommended to clear the keyslots as described in 5.3 of http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#5._Security_Aspects. Go ahead and ask about erasing encrypted disks.

Comment: @TomBrossman The link you posted is now broken, so I'm just posting [an archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140701074200/https://ssd.eff.org/tech/deletion) here.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

### Securely erasing a storage device

There's a command-line utility called `shred`, which overwrites data in a file or a whole device with random bits, making it nearly impossible to recover.

First of all, you need to identify the name of the device.

This might be something like `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/hdb` (but **not** like `/dev/sdb1`, that's a partition). You can use `sudo fdisk -l` to list all connected storage devices, and find your external hard drive there.

**N.B. Make sure it is the correct device, picking the wrong device will wipe it.**

Unmount all currently mounted partitions on that device, if any.
Then run the following, replacing `/dev/sdX` with the name of your device:

```
sudo shred -v /dev/sdX
```

This will overwrite all the blocks on the device with random data three times, the `-v` flag is for verbose and will print the current progress.

You can add the option `-n`*`N`* to only do this *N* times, to save time on large capacity devices. This might take a while, depending on the size of your external hard drive (I think it takes twenty minutes or so for my 4 GB flash drive).

You can also set all bits to zero after the last iteration by adding the option `-z`, I prefer to do this.

```
sudo shred -v -n1 -z /dev/sdX
```

After this, you would have to repartition the device. The easiest way is to install GParted and use it:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
gksu gparted
```

Choose your device in the upper-right corner list. Then select `Device -> Create partition table` to create a partition table on the device.

Then add a single partition that uses all of the unallocated space on the device, choosing `fat32` as the file system. Apply the changes by click the **Apply** button (the green checkmark) in the toolbar.

### Tips

- Read the [manpage for `shred` online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/shred.1.html) or by typing `man shred` in the terminal.
- Beware that some parts of your disk will not be erased - use the drive firmware "SECURE ERASE" command, such as via hdparm, to properly clean off a disk.

Comment: Best practice here: disconnect all of your hard drives, plug in the external drive and then do the above off of a live CD to prevent even the possibility of fragging anything that matters.

Comment: Just a question: You wrote "`shred` would then overwrite all the data on the device with random data three times." - does it do anything for empty space? Btw, Ubuntu has it own manpage repository at manpages.ubuntu.com

Comment: @papukaija It should.

Comment: Note that this answer has been deprecated by the SECURE ERASE method of requesting the drive to erase itself. This should take care of all possible data, and won't unnecessarily tax your system. You can perform a secure erase, where the drive erases itself, using the `hdparm` utility. This method tries to erase the entire drive, including bad sectors. Furthermore it is much faster than overwriting the normal way. It is also the recommended methods for SSD drives, where `shred` is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: according to manual:  shred - overwrite a file to hide its contents, and optionally delete it

Comment: In my case I just wanted to shred a partition so `shred /dev/sdc4` seems to be working.

Comment: @owlstead: Could you elaborate? What is SECURE ERASE, and how does one use it? It's appreciated if you make a separate answer if you have a better one.

Comment: The comment about using ATA Secure Erase command is misleading. There are serious problems with using SE (regarding the lack of consistent support from vendors and the lack of transparency on the process). Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62253/

Comment: Just a note, if you use a RAID controller on a HP proliant server, then if you add the HDD you want to wipe, then you must use hpacucli to create a new logical drive, before it shows up in Linux. at which point the above works fine.

Comment: @Frxstrem Why do you say "nearly" impossible to recover? Wouldn't the `shred` command make it *absolutely* impossible to recover the data?

Comment: @Fiksdal I don't know, it's been five years since I wrote this answer and I don't remember my motivations for phrasing it that way. That said, I think I meant it along the lines of "practically impossible today but plausably possible in the future with enough technological improvement".

Comment: Would someone like to write a complete answer about how to use hdparm to wipe a disk?

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this I found working solution here for hdparm: https://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=16716

Comment: Another good tutorial for secure erase with hdparam is here: https://code.mendhak.com/securely-wipe-ssd/

Comment: @AmanicA shred doesn't work with individual partitions, remove the 4 to erase the whole entire drive of sdc

Comment: I don't think `gparted` is necessary since the question is about secure erasing; not preparation for subsequent use. I think an operating system installer will not need you to do such preparation.

Answer (score 127):

Just 'zero' it using the `dd` tool:

1. Start the Disk Utility via `System > Administration > Disk Utility`
2. Find your disk in the left panel, select it, and on the right find the device path (eg. `/dev/sdX` )
3. Run the following command from a terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal):
   `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M`
   Make sure you use the right device path and **not** just copy this line!

This will overwrite the whole disk with zeros and is considerably faster than generating gigabytes of random data. Like all the other tools this won't take care of blocks that were mapped out for whatever reason (write errors, reserved, etc.), but it's highly unlikely your buyer will have the tools and the knowledge to recover anything from those blocks.

PS: Before you Bruce Schneier fanboys downvote me: I want proof that it's possible to recover data from a non-ancient rotational hard drive that has been overwritten with zeros. Don't even think about commenting otherwise! :P

Comment: +1 for Bruce Schneier (and DD which really is an excellent tool)

Comment: Not saying this is the strongest "proof" but [the Gutmann method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method) exists for a reason. As far as I know, modern hard drives are still theoretically susceptible to having their data recovered if it's been overwritten by zeros. Whether or not that still holds, hopefully you can admit it's not going to hurt by overwriting using /dev/random or a specific algorithm for that purpose.

Comment: No, it won't hurt, it just will take a lot of time (especially if you use /dev/random :P) with questionable benefit. The last paper on that topic I read (sorry, no details, I think it was from 2008) suggested - based on data from tests with real hardware - that the chance to recover a single bit is <50% → means you get a lower error rate when "recovering" each bit using a coin toss. So, unless there's proof that zero-ing isn't enough (it's no "maybe" right now, rather a "no friggin' way"), this is the method of choice for me.

Comment: Wouldn't /dev/urandom be faster than /dev/random, anyway?

Comment: Actually, a **lot** faster (that's why I used the ":P" smiley ;)). If you don't generate enough "randomness", /dev/random will even block reads (`man urandom` for more information).

Comment: @Cerin My understanding is that there has **never** been any proof that these paranoid data recovery fantasies are even possible. As pointed out in the ["Criticism"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method#Criticism) section of the article you linked, Guttman himself is critical of how his algorithm has been used "*more as a kind of voodoo incantation to banish evil spirits than the result of a technical analysis of drive encoding techniques*". The only reasons to do more than zero-wipe a drive are emotional ... i.e. it makes you feel better ... not technical.

Comment: As shown in the research paper found at https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2009/01/15/overwriting-hard-drive-data/  , a single, complete pass with zeros is enough.

Comment: Nice, but could you kindly explain me why did you put the `bs=1M` parameter? I can read the `man`, and IIUC you are just limiting the buffer to 1 megabyte; why is doing so desirable?

Comment: Not an expert, but I hear that with current kernels (and without knowledge necessary to be able to set all the dd magic right), it's normally enough to just `cat </dev/zero >/dev/sdX`.

Comment: @AloisMahdal tested your assertion and yes, there's no difference in my laptop/SSD

Comment: @gaazkam the default size is 512b. Each write operation takes time to complete, so increasing the amount of data being written during each write should increase throughput. This is what I see when using `dd ... status=progress` or in tools like `iotop` as well. Theoretically, the largest payload write size your hardware can support would likely result in the fewest number of write operations.

Comment: Note that DD does not support >2TB drives - if you're using a modern disk, it will *say* it erased it, but it will not have erased the last part.

Comment: @user8675309 - Can you clarity "the largest payload write size your hardware can support would likely result in the fewest number of write operations"?

Comment: @cnd - Can you refer to an authoritative source that notes the lack of support for drives greater than 2TB?

Comment: I have a reason for NOT using `/dev/zero` sometimes: File systems with transparent compression like BTRFS or ZFS compress a lot of those `0` and only VERY few of those to disk. Somewhat defeating the purpose. :-)

Comment: @Thorsten: `dd` to `/dev/sdX` bypasses any filesystem on the drive. There is no btrfs or zfs in the middle compressing things, or deduplicating blocks. Of course one should not specify a higher level block device, but replace the `sdX` placeholder with the lowest level, closest to the hardware, block device descriptor. The comment does not apply to this answer.

Comment: You have more security with a smaller bs argument. For example on an 80 GB HDD and an argument of 1M it turns out that 76,293 records were written for a total of 79,999,008,768 bytes. With an argument of 64K 1,220,703 records were written for a total of 79,999,991,808 bytes. These runs took approximately the same amount of time. The bs parameter defaults to 512 bytes which I did not try. Since the result is sensitive to the bs parameter, this solution is flawed. @gaazkam

Answer (score 33):

I generally use a destructive read-write test using [`badblocks -w`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks). The two major advantages are:

- it's part of the base system and almost every rescue system, so it is available e.g. from the rescue shell of the Ubuntu installer
- you get a report at the end whether there are bad blocks on the disk

Note that if the report indicates a problem, I'd no longer sell the disk as it is likely to fail soon.

Also Note: The `-w` does a 4-pass destructive write test by default.

> Use write-mode test. With this option, badblocks scans for bad blocks by writing some patterns (0xaa, 0x55, 0xff, 0x00) on every block of the device, reading every block and comparing the contents.

Usage example (if your disk is `sdd`):

```
sudo badblocks -wsv /dev/sdd
```

(added `sv` for progress bar + verbose)

For a much faster wipe, add the `-t` option and do a single pass of zeros like so:

```
sudo badblocks -wsv -t 0x00 /dev/sdd
```

Answer (score 27):

Best is to use the [secure erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) function of ATA drives. Secure erase erases the drive at firmware level. Can't get more secure.

First check if secure erase is supported:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdX | grep -i security
```

(replace sdX with sda/sdb/sdc, whatever your disk is).

If you see no output, just use dd:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M
```

If you see output, check if the device is not frozen:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdX | grep -i frozen
```

If it is frozen, see [How to unfreeze drive in Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/1161531/162491)
Otherwise if you see `not frozen`, set password to "Eins":

```
sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass Eins /dev/sdX
```

Optional: you might want to know how how long this will take:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdX | awk '/for SECURITY ERASE UNIT/'
```

Then execute the erase:

```
sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-erase Eins /dev/sdX
```

Then wait. Apparently for a 1TB disk this might take 3 hours or more.

There's a [nice script which automated these steps](https://github.com/TigerOnVaseline/ata-secure-erase).

Comment: From [Wikipedia - Gutmann method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method): *However, a 2011 research found that 4 out of 8 manufacturers did not implement ATA Secure Erase correctly.*

Comment: Why not `--security-erase-enhanced`?

Answer (score 25):

Now, **Disks** (**`gnome-disks`**) tool has [*ATA Secure Erase*](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase). You may use it to erase your hard drive. Same option explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/42277/26246) using the command-line tool `hdparm`.

---

**WARNING!**

> Please, review disclaimer and warning notes at https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase (Thanks to [@colan](https://askubuntu.com/users/24860/colan) to bring this up)
>
> Also comments below. Some hardware may break.

---

1. Open Disks tool → Choose the target disk
2. From menu: Format Disk...
3. Select from drop box, Erase: `ATA Enhanced Secure Erase` ( if offered for the drive you selected ). Alternatively you can select `Write zeros (slow)` which can reasonably be considered to be secure.
4. Format

[image: ATA Enhanced Secure Erase 1]

[image: ATA Enhanced Secure Erase 2]

Comment: While this is the best option generally, it does not apply over USB (as asked in the above question).  There are warnings and disclaimers about that at https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase.  Nevertheless, I asked about it in the [Gnome issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility/issues/87).

Comment: @colan As I understand that depends on the feature support in the full stack (Disks - Kernel - Driver - Controller - Drive). While my case was ok for two HDD's (WD USB3 HDD & WD w/ SATA-USB3 active adapter), I confirm it is not for all cases, I have seen some SATA-USB3 adapters with hard-coded block alignment (reading with 512b & 4k block does not create identical images), some doesn't support SMART which has some long exec commands too, Some USB Drives has a non-standardized/twisted implementation for password-protected/encrypted partition (Using it through another USB adapter will break it)

Comment: @colan if the USB interface thinks the drive has fallen asleep during ATA Secure Erase, the write zeros alternative on the same menu is useful.  Writing zeros keeps the USB interface looking alive.

Comment: The same menu that offers ATA Secure Erase (if and when available) also offers to write zeros (slow) or to mark deletion (fast but not secure). The zeroing can reasonably be considered secure so this answer should be generalized to recommend that option. As a GUI solution it might reasonably be considered to be superior to the command line `shred` solution. The much up-voted `dd` solution is flawed and I posted a comment to document why it is so.

Answer (score 23):

Have a look at this definitive question on Security Stack Exchange

**[How can I reliably erase all information on a hard drive](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5749/485)**

This discusses various secure deletion options, along with physical destruction and wiping so you can decide which option may be your best bet.

Remember though that the current recovery status for different storage is as follows:

- Very old hard drives: there were gaps between tracks so you could potentially pick up bleed into these gaps (if you had a scanning electron microscope handy). Overwriting multiple times was potentially useful.
- New hard drives: no technology currently exists that can read after even one overwrite.
- Solid state hard drives: wear levelling means you cannot overwrite securely. Instead you either encrypt the entire volume and dispose of the key to wipe, or you destroy the device.

Comment: What is the definition of very old e.g. 30 years ago?

Comment: 10Mb MFM drives from around 20-25 years ago, yes

Comment: How does this relate to drives in devices such as mobile phones and tablets?

Comment: @Motivated Given that phones and tablets use flash memory, it's probably the same answer as for SSD's, but I'm not sure. You could ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for better info.

Comment: Since you mentioned SSD (apart from HDD), the answer you linked, links to an SSD specific question which says that in order to be secure the encryption is to happen before the information hits the SSD. Encrypting the drive afterwards does not protect the information that was already there. In other words, encrypting afterwards is not equivalent to erasure.

Comment: That post also says some SSD drives like the Intel 320 Series already supports encryption. Perhaps Ubuntu knows it does not need to treat every SSD the same way. But still we should "ask for" encryption thru Ubuntu, again, before the information hits the SSD.

Comment: @H2ONaCl - you don't encrypt afterwards to erase! You have the entire volume encrypted so that when you dispose of the key, everything on the drive is unreadable forever.

Answer (score 9):

- You need to create a loopback device which runs /dev/random over the entire contents of the drive.
- That'll fill the entire drive with almost completely random data.Then you can set all bits back to 0 with dd.
- Actually, dd should be able to randomize all of the information.
- You said that you have stored banking information on your harddisk.So i would suggest you to run any one of the following command from a live cd (where **hdX** is your harddrive).

  `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hdX`

  `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/hdX`

  `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/hdX`
- How ever it will take a very long time based on your harddisk size.

**For your information:**

See the following links,

- **[Tools to delete files securely in ubuntu Linux](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tools-to-delete-files-securely-in-ubuntu-linux.html)**
- **[Use an Ubuntu Live CD to Securely Wipe Your PC’s Hard Drive](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15037/use-an-ubuntu-live-cd-to-securely-wipe-your-pcs-hard-drive/)**

**Note:**

- Random uses random bits and zero uses 0 bits.
- Urandom is a semi-random version of random.

Comment: Is random really  necessary? Would it not be sufficient to replace all bits with 1 and then with 0?

Comment: Never use /dev/random for such operations. /dev/random generates random data using an entropy pool and blocks the operation if this entropy pool is empty. So if you don't do anything with your computer to generate new randomness, the operation will take forever. Use /dev/urandom instead. Also see `man random`

Answer (score 8):

you can use [wipe](http://wipe.sourceforge.net/)

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install wipe
```

You can use that software or use the following command:

```
shred -vfz -n ? (drive)
```

*Were the "?" is, put the number of times you wan to shred the drive, then for were "(drive)" is, put the drive that you want to shred. Once your done, do whatever you want with it. I think that this method is more effective since you can control what is done to your drive and have immediate results.*

**Links**

1. http://wipe.sourceforge.net/
2. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15037/use-an-ubuntu-live-cd-to-securely-wipe-your-pcs-hard-drive/
3. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=817882

Comment: Why use one over the other, wipe vs shred?

Answer (score 7):

One more advantage of shred over dd in this scenario:
I have a faulty disk that I need to return to the vendor for an exchange.

dd halts at the first bad block, and fails to clobber the rest (unless I painfully use skip=... to jump ahead each time it stops).

shred ignores write errors and happily continues in this case.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [DBAN](http://www.dban.org). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBAN):

> Darik's Boot and Nuke (commonly known
>   as DBAN) [...] is designed to securely
>   erase a hard disk until data is
>   permanently removed and no longer
>   recoverable, which is achieved by
>   overwriting the data with random
>   numbers generated by Mersenne twister
>   or ISAAC (a PRNG). The Gutmann method,
>   Quick Erase, DoD Short (3 passes), and
>   DOD 5220.22-M (7 passes) are also
>   included as options to handle Data
>   remanence.
>
> DBAN can be booted from a floppy disk,
>   CD, DVD, or USB flash drive and it is
>   based on Linux. It supports PATA
>   (IDE), SCSI and SATA hard drives. DBAN
>   can be configured to automatically
>   wipe every hard disk that it sees on a
>   system, making it very useful for
>   unattended data destruction scenarios.
>   DBAN exists for Intel x86 and PowerPC
>   systems.
>
> DBAN, like other methods of data
>   erasure, is suitable for use prior to
>   computer recycling for personal or
>   commercial situations, such as
>   donating or selling a computer[2]. In
>   the case of malware infection, DBAN
>   can be used before returning a disk to
>   production.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lsblk` to get the disk name.

**CAUTION: Don't zero-fill an SSD, ever.** Find more details [here](https://serverfault.com/a/282583).

In case of HDD, you can use the following commands.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4096 count=2013054 status=progress
```

or,

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX bs=4096 count=2013054 status=progress
```

or,

```
sudo dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sdX bs=4096 count=2013054 status=progress
```

Replace `X` with appropriate letter.

Please note that you need to use `count=` otherwise you will get `dd: error writing '/dev/sdX': No space left on device`

To calculate `count=`, you can use the following command.

```
echo $(($(df --output=size -B1 /dev/sda | tail -1)/4096))
```

Please replace `4096` with your `bs=` value.

For NVMe or SATA SSD, read on. From now on the following **CAUTION** will be applicable.

**CAUTION: Do not proceed with this if the target drive is not connected directly to a SATA/NVMe interface. Issuing the Secure Erase/Format/Sanitize command on a drive connected via USB or a SAS/RAID card could potentially brick the drive!**

For SATA SSD drive check [SATA SSD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive/Memory_cell_clearing#SATA_drive).

For NVMe drive check [NVMe Drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive/Memory_cell_clearing#NVMe_drive).

Comment: @user68186 without `status=progress` it is very hard to track changes. It was not mentioned anywhere else. That is why I added this answer.

Comment: You should say that up front in the beginning of your answer. You may also say something about SSDs. This is not 2010 any more, In 2022 SSDs are more common in many places than HDDs. Using `dd` on SSDs is not a great idea, I think.

Comment: Read the [second answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/282555/zeroing-ssd-drives) which says "**Don't zero-fill an SSD, ever.**."

Comment: @user68186 please review my answer and let me know if anything needs to be changed. Thank you very much for raising the SSD specific issues (I did not know that earlier). By putting my note as a answer here, I learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 0):

Go root and

```
dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/(your usb drive device here); dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/(your usb drive device here)
```

Be certain you've got the right drive!

Comment: Never use /dev/random for such operations. /dev/random generates random data using an entropy pool and blocks the operation if this entropy pool is empty. So if you don't do anything with your computer to generate new randomness, the operation will take forever. Use /dev/urandom instead. Also see `man random`

Comment: You probably would need to prefix the command with `sudo`. Also, `dd` tends to complete sooner when a block size larger than the default is used. So I would suggest **very carefully** using: `sudo dd if=/dev/random bs=1m of=/dev/sdX`

Comment: ah, meant that to be `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1m of=/dev/sdX` Oh, well.

Answer (score 0):

DBAN is an open source Boot CD to wipe the hard disk.

Down load from

http://www.dban.org/download

burn it and boot the machine from CD, that's all.

Comment: Already suggested: http://askubuntu.com/a/51979/8530

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do that is use :

```
sudo shred -fv /dev/xxx
```

where xxx is device, to ensure what device you have, type :

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

The device are indicated after **disk** word and to the colon char **:**, like this :

```
Disk /dev/sde: 500.1 GB etc...
```

Don't mount file systems of your disk you want wipe etc.
Shred will do what you want in part of time. -z option is for last run with 0 to hide wipe and is not necessary to wipe data.

Best way is to use dd like wrote previous users:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/xxx bs=1M
```

use **urandom device** as it is more modern and better way to obtain random pattern.

Other tools at this moment can be older and by less people develop. Shred is in core application of Linux.

Look at this example: [wipe 2009](http://lambda-diode.com/software/wipe/) http://lambda-diode.com/software/wipe/. But it is known app.
It is possible to use bleachbit but as I tried it took long time.

Answer (score 0):

If the dd cmd is not working, you can use the redirection method to wipe out the data.

Like,

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/sd**a**   # depends on your hdd location
```

or

alternatively you can use cp (copy cmd) to overwrite the previous data.

```
cp /dev/urandom /dev/sd**a**      # depends on your hdd location
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nwipe, it's command line or ncurses GUI. Has multiple wipe methods. Can wipe many devices simultaneously. It's the more up to date version of DBAN and is currently maintained. Nwipe can be found in most Linux distros and is available as a bootable USB version called Shredos

Nwipe https://github.com/martijnvanbrummelen/nwipe

Shredos https://github.com/PartialVolume/shredos.2020.02

Answer (score 0):

You can use pv to zero-fill it and you'll even get a nice progress bar:

```
pv < /dev/zero > /dev/sdX
```

where sdX is the device of the drive to delete; you can get that from this command:

```
lsblk
```

Taken from [pv(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html)

You can also one-fill it with pv:

```
tr '\0' '\377' < /dev/zero | pv > /dev/sdX
```

Partially taken from [monkeybus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18534993/17011606)

Answer (score -1):

Those recommending to use shred are giving bad advice. Shred's own man page says it's effectively useless on journaled filesystems, which Ubuntu is almost guaranteed to be using if you don't change its filesystem defaults (ext3 and ext4 are journaled. As is resierfs and Reiser4 as well as many MANY other common Linux filesystems.).

Not to mention shred is completely useless for completely blanking or randomizing a disk, as it only works on individual files or sets of files (On the filesystem level, not a raw data level.). If you want to securely wipe a disk, you gotta use dd on the drive's main device node (For example: /dev/sdc instead of /dev/sdc1) while nothing is mounted on it.

It WILL take a while, but unlike shred it will completely and IRREVERSIBLY wipe a hard disk from MBR to final sector. Also, BIG WARNING on dd, make sure you are using it on the correct device or you'll at least PARTIALLY wipe the wrong disk. This could be disastrous if you accidentally use dd on a system drive, which will not only make it unbootable, but may irreversibly corrupt any given partition on the drive. This has given it the nickname "disk destroyer."

Shred is NOT a reliable tool for securely wiping a drive. If you're selling or giving your computer away the CORRECT way to empty the drive is to zero or randomize it with dd and never, ever use shred, as filesystem journals will effectively restore shredded files with no effort at all.

Comment: You don't point shred at a file. You point it at the entire device. The filesystem is irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidGiven Well technically you can shred just a file inside a filesystem, and that's what shred manpage talks about for the most part. Yaro's warnings would be sort-of valid in that case.  But yes, shredding a whole partition is a completely different thing; in that case the filesystem indeed does not matter.