# What is the recommended way to empty a SSD?

Tags: ssd, trim

I've just received my new SSD since the old one died. This Intel 320 SSD supports TRIM. For testing purposes, my dealer put Windows on it, but I want to get rid of this and install Kubuntu on it.

It does not have to be a "secure wipe", I just need the empty the disk in the most healthy way. I believe that `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda` just fills the blocks with zeroes and thereby taking another write (correct me if I'm wrong).

I've seen the answer [How to enable TRIM](https://askubuntu.com/q/18903/6969), but it looks like it's suited for clearing empty blocks, not wiping the disk.

`hdparm` seems to be the program to do it, but I'm not sure if it clears the disk OR cleans empty blocks. From its manual page:

> ```
>   --trim-sector-ranges
>           For  Solid State Drives (SSDs).  EXCEPTIONALLY DANGEROUS. DO NOT
>           USE THIS OPTION!!  Tells the drive firmware to discard  unneeded
>           data  sectors,  destroying  any  data that may have been present
>           within them.  This makes those sectors available  for  immediate
>           use  by  the firmware's garbage collection mechanism, to improve
>           scheduling for wear-leveling of the flash  media.   This  option
>           expects  one  or  more  sector range pairs immediately after the
>           option: an LBA starting address, a colon, and  a  sector  count,
>           with no intervening spaces.  EXCEPTIONALLY DANGEROUS. DO NOT USE
>           THIS OPTION!!
> ```

```
          E.g.  hdparm --trim-sector-ranges 1000:4 7894:16 /dev/sdz
```

How can I make all blocks appear as empty using TRIM?

Comment: Good question, maybe it's enough to just delete the NTFS filesystem?

Comment: @htorque: "maybe" is still not confirming, any useful sources would be welcome.

Comment: Hence it's just a comment. ;) However, you could first check some sectors on that partition `sudo dd if=/dev/sda iflag=direct bs=512 skip=<some_sectors> count=32 | hexdump -C`, then delete the NTFS partition using a recent Gparted version and re-check with the same command - if the data got wiped, you'd just see zeroes.

Comment: @htorque: I've just tested it but it's not working, I've used `hexdump -C /sda1` and `hexdump -C /sda1` to determine the starting block. Nice idea though.

Comment: Would have been too easy, wouldn't it? :) Anyways, thanks for trying!

Comment: @Lekensteyn - with a modern SSD I really wouldn't worry about one more write. That isn't what will kill it:-) Read Jeff Atwood's take. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-hot-crazy-solid-state-drive-scale.html

Comment: @Rory: (haven't read the article yet) the controller I guess? That killed my last SSD. By the way, I'm worried about the performance, see also http://www.anandtech.com/show/2865/2

Comment: @Lekensteyn - I meant it slightly tongue in cheek and popped a proper answer for you below. Jeff's article has a bit on performance as well, which is why he uses them despite the failure rate:-)

Comment: I still don't see why you need to erase it... why can't you just reformat it with Ext4 or whatever?

Comment: See http://www.anandtech.com/show/2865/2

Answer (score 70, accepted):

## ATA Secure Erase

You should use the drive's [security erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) feature.

1. **Make sure the drive Security is not frozen**. If it is, it may help to suspend and resume the computer.

   ```
   $ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdX | grep frozen
          not     frozen
   ```

   The (filtered) command output means that this drive is ”not frozen” and you can continue.
2. **Set a User Password** (this password is cleared too, the exact choice does not matter).

   ```
   sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass Eins /dev/sdX
   ```
3. **Issue the ATA Secure Erase command**

   ```
   sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-erase Eins /dev/sdX
   ```

**Note:**

- `/dev/sdX` is the SSD as a block device that you want to erase.
- `Eins` is the password chosen in this example.

See the [*ATA Secure Erase* article in the Linux kernel wiki](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) for complete instructions including troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks good for those who have a BIOS that supports it, but mine does not appear to support it. (frozen)

Comment: Hurrah! After reading the article again, I read "Placing my system into "sleep" (Clevo M865TU notebook) worked too---and this may reset other drives to "not frozen" as well." and tried it since mine is originally from Clevo as well (but [BTO](http://bto.eu/) build it). It works, I see "not frozen" now. ... but step 3 failed with "ERASE_PREPARE: Bad address" **because I replaced sudo by time** instead of prepending to the command!

Comment: OMG it worked and only took 19 seconds! Thanks a bunch! I wish I could upvote you ten times :D

Comment: I just wanted to report that the accepted answer above has a broken link. It's pretty useless without said link, anyone care to post a summary of what that link said?

Comment: @Ashimema: The link is currently broken because kernel.org had been hacked and therefore down for maintenance. Google Cache is empty, but this blog copied it: http://peter.membrey.hk/2011/09/11/secure-erase-wiki-no-long-available-instructions-on-how-to-securely-erase-your-ssd/

Comment: On a Kingston SSDNow V100 (64GB), this erase process took noticebly longer, namely 7 *minutes*.

Comment: Note: This does not work over **USB** (as is mentioned in the [link](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) given above but which I only read after trying). P.S. Thank you!

Comment: I tried this on two drives attached via USB and it worked exactly as described. Am running Mint 17.2  with Kernel 3.19.0-25-generic on a Thinkpad X230.

Comment: What is the reason for recommending secure erase rather than `--trim-sector-ranges`?

Comment: @kasperd, only that it it is likely to be faster since it is only a single command, vs many ( one for each x size block of space ).

Comment: @psusi The potential issues with security settings, and having to deal with setting a password sounds more significant to me than waiting a few minutes for some TRIM commands to be issued. And secure erase sounds like overkill. Doesn't the need for secure erase to ensure that data is gone immediately and cannot be recovered mean that it causes more wear on the SSD than a simple TRIM which just needs to ensure that cells are ready for reuse and not necessarily unrecoverable immediately?

Comment: I suppose you mean the first command is `hdparm -I /dev/sdX`.

Comment: @kasperd, whether the erase is done now ( for secure erase ) or postponed until later ( for trim ), the wear on the cells is the same.  In fact, the wear may be less with the secure erase since with trim, the drive might have to make several commits to the flash translation log before all of the trims have been issued.  With the secure erase, it is just one full drive erase.  This is another reason why it tends to be faster.

Comment: @jarno, good catch; fixed it.

Comment: FYI, if it does say `frozen`, suspend the system and log back in to return it to a `not frozen` state. The other option is to unplug the sata cable from the drive while the machine is running, but you have to be very careful when doing so.

Comment: @HatemJaber, I'm pretty sure that it is the *power* you have to remove, not disconnect the SATA cab le, in order to get the drive to unlock.  I guess power is included if you have the wide SATA connector but most people still use the small connector and separate molex connector for power, at least in desktops.  Pulling those is dangerous, but the full SATA connector with power is hot plug safe.

Comment: @psusi, I read that somewhere and fortunately did not have to do that; I actually seen that as a suggestion on several sites as I was researching the topic. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I had an unresponsive drive, freezing whole computer after some activity. Tried to clean it by above process, but the result is, that now even `hdparm -I /dev/hdX` reports `Model Number: SandForce{200026BB}` instead of `Model Number: INTEL SSDSC2BF180A5L` it reported before the erase. Fdisk reports *32768 bytes* of drive capacity, so it seems things are now even worse, than before. Use with extreme care!

Comment: @MaciekŁoziński, that tends to happen when an SSD dies.  It's now reporting what the controller actually is since it can't read the drive model information from the dead flash.

Answer (score 43):

util-linux 2.23 offers `blkdiscard` which discards data without secure-wiping them. I tested: works over SATA and mmcblk but not USB.

An excerpt from the manual page of `blkdiscard(8)`:

> #### NAME
>
> blkdiscard - discard sectors on a device
>
> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> blkdiscard [-o offset] [-l length] [-s] [-v] device
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> blkdiscard is used to discard device sectors.  This is useful for
>   solid-state drivers (SSDs) and thinly-provisioned storage.  Unlike
>   fstrim(8) this command is used directly on the block device.
>
> By default, blkdiscard will discard all blocks on the device.  Options may be used to modify this behavior based on range or size, as explained below.
>
> The device argument is the pathname of the block device.
>
> **WARNING: All data in the discarded region on the device will be lost!**

The command is there since Ubuntu 15.04 and OpenSUSE 13.1 (yes OpenSUSE has it 2 years ahead of Ubuntu).

Comment: thx for adding information to this outdated post and welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Arch Linux already has this package as util-linux 2.23 was released on 25 April 2013.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Outdated post? Old, but not outdated, as long as it pops up in 1st page of Google search result, there are always new guys looking for the same answer coming here. To me it is outdated only when better pages push it out of 1st google result page.

Comment: For the interested, the various IOCTLs are documented in this blog post: http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/blkdiscard-blkzeroout-blkdiscardzeroes-blksecdiscard/

Comment: If you are wondering the difference between `blkdiscard` and the `hdparm` command, it is answered [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/util-linux-ng/msg10351.html): "When you use blkdiscard, the SSD (assuming a SATA SSD) will receive an ATA TRIM command, whereas hdparm --security-erase will issue an ATA SECURITY ERASE UNIT command. What the drive then actually does is dependant on the implementation details of that particular SSD's firmware."

Comment: Note: This does not seem to work over **USB**.

Comment: You actually *don't* want to use `blkdiscard`.  First, it is intended to inform the drive that specific parts of it *may* be thrown out, not to wipe the whole thing.  The drive may or may not actually erase the data.  The secure erase command *must* erase all data, including any data that is in parts of the drive that are not currently accessible.  Edit: just re-read the question and realized it did not require erasure, but it is still worth noting.

Comment: **Note for this to work as expected** (the device returning zero-bytes after the TRIM, instead of _arbitrary_ data), I suspect **the SSD must support the [Deterministic Read Zero after TRIM (RZAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)#Hardware_support) feature** (check for it using `hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep 'Deterministic read ZEROs after TRIM'`).  Some of my SSDs support it but relatively recent Samsung 850 EVO doesn't. Continuing ...

Comment: ... [This post](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/samsung-840-850-pro-more-fatal-trim-firmware-bugs.2435924/#post-37487990) shows that despite the RZAT spec, _"**TRIM [as a whole] is only advisory**, [...] and the device is free to silently ignore all or parts of the request"_. And Linux does "whitelist drives that are known to reliably return zeroes after TRIM"_. [Source in the kernel code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e64f638483a21105c7ce330d543fa1f1c35b5bc7/drivers/ata/libata-core.c#L4109-L4286).

Comment: Given that the OP's request was “I just need the empty the disk in the most healthy way”, it sounds like `blkdiscard`ing the whole device, then zeroing the first few MiB is *the* play here, right? Whether **or not** it actually supports RZAT?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need a secure wipe, why don't you just install kubuntu using the options to 'use entire disk' and the equivalent of 'quick format' (can't remember the exact terminology right now)

That way you ditch the file allocation table and the drive is effectively emptied for overwriting. You don't actually need to empty it.

Comment: See http://www.anandtech.com/show/2865/2. Deleting the block is not the same as erasing it and marking it as empty.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Deleting doesn't mean anything for a block device.  The installer will call mkfs.ext4 and discard the entire device; this is as secure as a "secure erase", in the sense that in both cases you are trusting the SSD firmware.

Comment: @Tobu Right, that has changed at some point. `mkfs.ext4(8)` says: *discard - Attempt  to discard blocks at mkfs time (discarding blocks initially is useful on solid state devices and sparse / thin-provisioned storage). When the device advertises that discard also zeroes data (any subsequent read after the discard and before write returns zero), then mark all not-yet-zeroed inode tables as zeroed. This significantly speeds up filesystem initialization. This  is set as default.*

Comment: @Tobu For my use case, "Secure erase" did not have to really wipe the data from its flash chips, it should just ensure that there are no negative performance effects resulting from having some blocks in use.

Answer (score 3):

If the drive has a Linux filestem on it, you can use `fstrim`.
By default recent Ubuntu runs `fstrim` on drives from the following vendors:

```
    if [ -z "$NO_MODEL_CHECK" ]; then
        if ! contains "$HDPARM" "Intel" && \
           ! contains "$HDPARM" "INTEL" && \
           ! contains "$HDPARM" "Samsung" && \
           ! contains "$HDPARM" "SAMSUNG" && \
           ! contains "$HDPARM" "OCZ" && \
           ! contains "$HDPARM" "SanDisk" && \
           ! contains "$HDPARM" "Patriot"; then
            #echo "device $DEV is not a drive that is known-safe for trimming"
            continue
```

Once a week.

So one answer to your question is boot up the system and wait a week!

Comment: fstrim is mentioned in [this blkdiscard](http://askubuntu.com/a/351791/6969) post, you can also invoke it manually with `sudo fstrim /` (where `/` is a mountpoint of a filesystem that supports the `discard` option).

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the BIOS on the computer supports this.  On a laptop I just checked, there's an option to do a secure erase of all attached media on the next boot.  This is probably a widely used option in corporate environments, so many vendors probably include it now.  (I was checking on a Dell Precision 5510 laptop from 2017.)

Though if you just want to wipe the drive to install Linux (as per the question), you don't need to do a full wipe.  The only concern is that the drive should know that the space used previously by Windows is now free, to optimize SSD use.

There are many options for this, including those mentioned already.  I note that `mke2fs` has the `-E discard` option that should trim the partition when creating the file system, which is enabled by default.  (Note that this is the best effort option, so it will silently ignore it if the hardware doesn't support it.)  So in most cases you can simply ignore the problem, install Linux, and the installation process will do all the cleanup you need.

Answer (score -6):

Just remove the partition, you do not have to clear the whole disk, old data will be overwritten when the storage is needed for something else.

**To enable TRIM:**

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Change "ext4    errors=remount-ro 0" into "ext4    discard,errors=remount-ro 0". (Add discard)

Save and reboot, TRIM should now be enabled.

**Check if TRIM is enabled:**

```
sudo -i
dd if=/dev/urandom of=tempfile count=100 bs=512k oflag=direct
hdparm --fibmap tempfile
```

Use the first begin_LBA address.

```
hdparm --read-sector [begin_LBA] /dev/sda
```

Now it should return numbers and characters. Remove the file and sync.

```
rm tempfile
sync
```

Now, run the following command again. If it returns zeros TRIM is enabled.

```
hdparm --read-sector [begin_LBA] /dev/sda
```

Comment: You do NOT want to fill an SSD with zeros as it will write to every erase block, causing more wear and tear, and leaving every erase block full.  Also many drives do NOT immediately zero trimmed sectors.

Comment: Sure, it requires many writes, but it does not damage the disk.
I have used an Corsair F120 for 10-11 months now and have frequently filled it with zeros. (Doing it before every benchmark)
So, after 30-35 times the performance is still the same.(~285MB read, 275MB/write)
SMART says: The disk is healthy

Comment: Alex, every single write to an SSD damages it slightly.  Writing to every single erase block causes them all to be marked in use, which will prevent the drive's GC from functioning properly and performance will suffer.  You can think of it as a whole drive unTRIM.

Comment: It's not particularly significant that the SSD was still healthy after 30 rewrites. Recent Samsung SSDs for example have a warranty that expires after TBW equal to 200-600 times the size of the disk. So you'd need to test zeroing the disk a few hundred times before saying it doesn't wear out the disk. Of course you could also retort that if you just do it once then it's probably not such a big damage.