# What should I know about SSDs that can be used with Ubuntu?

Tags: ssd, hardware, compatibility

I'm building a new configuration and intend to buy an SSD with it. I recall that the first SSDs were problematic in Linux for some reason (maybe lack of TRIM support?).

Is there something to specifically avoid in today's SSDs? Or is it a safe bet to buy any?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've owned two SSD's, an OCZ Vertex 2 60GB (controller died in 5 months) and am now happy with an Intel 320 80GB.

I've had no issues with it in comparison with a mechanical HDD.

On the software side, most vendors provide utilities for SSDs which (unfortunately) only works in Windows due to [bug 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1). These fancy toolboxes often have an alternative in the repositories or system (examples: TRIM on-demand, erasing the disk). Since firmware updates should be applied when the disk is not in use, it's neither an issue for not using it in Linux.

Some interesting links:

- [What is the recommended way to empty a SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/42266/6969)
- [Optimize for SSD](https://askubuntu.com/q/1400/6969) (for SSDs supporting TRIM)
- [SSD Checklist](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MagicFab/SSDchecklist)

Not limited to Linux, but to SSDs in general: Jeff Atwood has an interesting [blog entry about the lifetime of a SSD](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-hot-crazy-solid-state-drive-scale.html). It should not stop you from buying a SSD, if it dies the manufacturer (or reseller) will replace it if it's within the warranty period. But the reason for buying one is it's **speed**. I was amazed with my first SSD, everything start almost instantly without hearing a disk spinning.

Comment: An informal but slightly larger sample size survey found that Crucial and Intel have the lowest return (defect) rate of the main SSD manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

No; it is a safe bet to buy any ( and always has been ).

As for TRIM, it is still disabled by default as it may ( though unlikely ) trigger bugs.  Depending on your workload, enabling it may, or may not improve the drive's performance over time.  To enable it, you need to add the `discard` option to your `/etc/fstab` file, like this:

```
UUID=xxx-xxx-xxx   /   ext4   errors=remount-ro,discard  0  1
```

Comment: This answer needs clarification.

Comment: @belacqua, no, it's a direct answer to the question.

Comment: @psusi  -- sorry, that was the auto-boilerplate from the review mechanism. However, this could definitely be fleshed out -- as it is, it doesn't respond to the question in the title, or second question ("is there or was there a problem with TRIM support"?), etc.. It does 'directly' answer in the sense (implied) that the only *necessary* answer is the one you provide -- that any SSD can be used.  I originally did not read this that optimistically.

Comment: @belacqua, I suppose I can add a bit more about TRIM.