# Do you recommend LUKS encryption on a SSD (TRIM support)?

Tags: ssd, luks, trim

I have a laptop (Dell Inspiron 11z) and and SSD (Samsung 128GB) on order.
On my current laptop, I have a spinning HDD and use LVM and LUKS encryption.

I would like to use LUKS on the SSD but from doing a bit of research I am not sure if this is desirable/possible.
It seems that LUKS (possibly???) may prevent TRIM from working.

I can't find any concrete info on this and lots of the info on SSDs such as alignment etc seems to be out of date.

Will TRIM work with LUKS? Because a laptop may be prone to theft, I like to have my data properly encrypted so this is important to me

Comment: Just FYI: the absence of TRIM commands doesn't affect all SSD in the same way, eg. SandForce controller based SSD don't take a big hit if there's no TRIM.

Answer (score 11):

TRIM does not work for LUKS encrypted partitions because the data being written on the disk is encrypted, even if a block is "empty" according to the filesystem. From cryptsetup 1.4 and later (supplied with 12.04 Precise) and Linux 3.1 (not supplied with Precise), TRIM *can* be enabled (it is not enabled by default for security reasons). See also [TRIM on an encrypted SSD](https://askubuntu.com/q/115823/6969)

If you begin to notice a big performance decrease, you should consider backing up the data, [clearing your SSD](https://askubuntu.com/q/42266/6969) and put the data back. (this may be a reinstall too)

Whether TRIM is supported or not for LUKS encrypted partitions, I'd certainly enable it unless your data isn't worth anything.

Answer (score 5):

LUKS does not allow TRIM by befault, because of [security concerns](https://superuser.com/a/318847).

Given the right versions of kernel and cryptsetup you can enable it though, either manually or on boot.

[I have posted a step by step guide](http://worldsmostsecret.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-activate-trim-on-luks-encrypted.html) to enabling TRIM with LUKS encrypted partitions in Ubuntu 12.04 or any Debian with cryptsetup 1.4+ and Kernel 3.1+. (Feel free to copy it here if some askubuntu guidelines deem it necessary.)

Answer (score 4):

See the "--allow-discards" option in the cryptsetup(8) man page and the "discard" option in the crypttab(5) man page.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to trim it manually with `fstrim` tool if everything configured correctly (subject is covered in various howtos). Aside "trim" support, speed decreases dramatically so advantages on using ssd with luks are questionable.