# Full disk encryption with SSD

Tags: encryption, ssd, performance, trim

I'm about to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.
If I use full encryption, which I desire, how will this impact performance of the SSD and FSTRIM?

Will I still be able to use it or will it be unnecessary?  Does full disk encryption simply create a giant file into which all my files go or does it create a barrier at the start of the disk and encrypts/decrypts files on the fly as I have seen both systems used in the past?

Comment: Explain what the 1st has to do with the 2nd please?

Comment: Anyone out there who can help?  Can I encrypt the HD during install and still use FSTRIM or are the two mutually exclusive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TRIM on an encrypted SSD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/115823/trim-on-an-encrypted-ssd)

Comment: @markrich: The performance overhead of and the availability of TRIM for full disk encryption are two separate issues (though TRIM has an additional performance impact itself). Please avoid asking multiple questions at once and split this question accordingly.