# Overprovisioning SSD on ubuntu. How? Ubuntu 19.04 Samsung SSD 860

Tags: ssd, 19.04

Do I just leave some space not partitioned and thats all?

Comment: please edit your question to indicate the version of Ubuntu yoou are using and what size SSD you propose. Will the SSD be your primary partition?

Comment: Done. I have 500gb ssd only. Yes, linux is already installed there. I never heard about over provisioning thing, so I thought about decreasing parition size "live" with gparted.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve? If your concern is write lifetime, note that using a smaller part of your SSD but exposing it to the same number of writes won't increase its lifetime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, a SSD works totally differently compared with a HDD. On latter you actually assigned physical disk space (cylinders) to partitions. On SSDs partitions are purely logical, the space actually used for storage is distributed by the internal controller, which takes wear leveling into account, among others.

SSD manufacturers usually already [overprovision their devices in the firmware](https://www.kingston.com/us/ssd/overprovisioning). You may increase that by leaving some (logical) space unpartitioned, so the controller has more free capacity to work with. Or you can create an unused partition which you label accordingly to make clear what you intended.

But speaking from my (limited) knowledge, for the usual use cases (typical workstation use, not too write intensive) you could just assign all available space to partitions, and take care that the total space you use (over all partitions) doesn't exceed a certain percentage. So you make the best use of the capacity you paid for, without needing to repartition later (at least if your partition schema was sufficiently appropriate for your use), which would be a *very* write intensive process.

Comment: Also look into `TRIM`. The SSD will not know which space is no longer used by the filesystem unless it is told.

Comment: Also check out Samsung Magician, since it's a Samsung SSD. It'll overprovion and TRIM for you with little setup

Comment: How to use Samsung Magician on Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/537471/samsung-magician-on-ubuntu-14-04#569581 However, applying `fstrim -va` once in a while is quite straightforward.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: It doesn't.  This works because nothing ever writes to unpartitioned space, so it remains in unwritten state even without TRIM.  (If a drive had *previously* been full, you need to TRIM or secure-erase / reset it before partitioning, though.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm not sure I understand correctly what your questions is aiming at. If I do, the answer is: The SSD controller doesn't need to know anything about partitions, because it works below the partition table/filesystem level, acts as interface between OS and hardware, mapping logical to physical units, and has complete control over access to the hardware.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think your answer is misinterpretative, as AFAIK there is no "unpartitioned space" on a SSD (at least not in the sense as it is on a HDD). Perhaps you want elaborate on what exactly you wanted to say?

Comment: @Murphy: When you make a partition table with `fdisk` or whatever, you leave some of space not part of any partition.  e.g. a trivial example: on a 256GB SSD, make a small boot partition, a 2GB swap partition, and a 200GB main partition, leaving about 54GB unused.  You could later create another partition, or grow the last existing partition, into that space.  Modern partitions are merely about subdividing the raw linear array of sectors/blocks that the raw block device presents.  (e.g. `/dev/sda` or `/dev/nvme0n1`).  All disk *formatting* of rotational media is left to the disk internals.

Comment: Rotational IDE / SATA disks only present a linear array of sectors, same as SSDs.  That's the whole point of "integrated drive electronics", if I understand correctly.

Comment: @PeterCordes IDE used to use CHS (cylinder/head/sector); LBA didn't come around until substantially later.

Comment: @chrylis: thanks.  But you still don't really get a choice of actually formatting it differently to get more or less storage.  It's still just a sequence of sectors with a well-agreed-upon order for traversing them.  i.e. there is a fixed conversion between linear and CHS for any given drive, so you can still logically think of partitioning as breaking up that linear space into regions, regardless of how you store addresses.  \@Murphy's comments and answer about rotational HDDs implies much lower level than it is: remapping of bad sectors to a small pool of spares is a thing for magnetic disks