# Zombie partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, encryption, gparted

[This issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713191/recovering-a-half-encrypted-disk) has evolved. <sup>IT'S ALIVEEEEEEEEEE!!!</sup>

After giving the disk a brand-new partition table (or that's what `gparted` would have me think it's done), this is what `gparted` shows:

[image: what the fuck, gparted.]

How great! Magical partitions and magical data that *I killed a week ago* have **come back from the dead**!

Fine, maybe `gnome-disks` can help the problem.

[image: what the fuck, udisks.]

Evidently, `udisks` and `gparted` are **conspiring** to make *me* smash my head on a brick!

Well, no matter, perhaps it will comply if I format it using `gnome-disks`... never mind.

[image: wtf, udisks.]

Then I tried formatting it with `gparted` again and it *seemed to comply!* However, as soon as Ubiquity tried to format it / run `partman` on it for an Ubuntu installation, Ubiquity crashed as it has before, at this screen:

[image: sweet.]

What do I do? Is there a magical tool which will soothe my Ubuntu installation woes, or need I buy a new disk? I *really* don't want to buy a new disk. <sub>I'm poor, okay??</sub>

I'm not tempted to believe I need a new disk, i.e. that this one is physically damaged because it's a few-months old SSD. It never leaves the compartment on my laptop, so I don't see how *encrypting it* equates to *physical damage*, but whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to throw this out there, but maybe you can try clearing the memory cells if you don't want any of the data on that drive.

Here is a great [step-by-step](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD_memory_cell_clearing) for memory cell clearing on a SSD drive.

Comment: This looks promising, thank you! If it works, and I can install, I'll accept this answer :)

Comment: @cat Sounds good to me.  =)

Comment: [Now I have another problem. Got any advice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252265)

Comment: @cat Try setting the security password to something other than `NUL` or `NULL`.  Try `PaSsWoRd`.  It's not going to matter, as the password gets reset after the erase is completed.

Comment: I tried `PaSsWoRd`, `password`, and the BIOS's password, all of which gave `Input/Output Error`

Comment: @cat Your line should read like this `hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass PasSWorD /dev/sdX`  Where did you get the `--user-master m` from?

Comment: I tried `--user-master u` before but I used `--user-master m` in the post because the BIOS has a master password set for the drive. `--user-master u` gives the same `Input/Output Error.`

Comment: @cat Have you tried disabling your bios boot password?

Comment: No, but I will now.

Comment: @cat I am very happy that you got it working!  =)  Have an awesome day!