# What is used in the 12.10 full disk encryption?

Tags: 12.10

I previously had been using TrueCrypt, but recently re-installed Ubuntu and used 12.10's full disk encryption option (re-installed for other reasons). I never got any choice in how it did that. I don't know what cipher is used or the key size, or anything besides the passphrase really. Where can I find details about this sda5_crypt?

Edit: Seeing this mistake is humorous, but for those curious, sda5 refers to the hard drive and partition, not the encryption system.

Comment: possible duplicates - http://askubuntu.com/questions/102271/are-there-any-known-vulnerabilities-to-ubuntus-full-disk-encryption-feature, and http://askubuntu.com/questions/187874/how-will-12-10-disk-encryption-affect-performance

Comment: Not an exact dupe but I think your [answer is here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94298/which-algorithm-does-encrypt-home-directory-use).

Comment: eCryptfs, flexible and easy to use. The only drawback I can think of is that it is NOT cross-platform like TrueCrypt (file container is so flexible). https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ecryptfs.html

Comment: Thank you Tom. I don't understand why that's not expressed to the user when they're setting it up.

Comment: To commentators above: please don't confuse eCryptfs (homedir) and dm-crypt (FDE).

Comment: Ok, mixed up there. So what is the default algorithm for FDE?

Edit: AES-XTS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full disk encryption is using the `dm-crypt` kernel module, managed by Luks/cryptsetup. If you choose to encrypt your home directory, eCryptfs is used instead. These are two different technologies. I assume you chose *full disk encryption* here in my answer.

Use the command

```
# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5
```

to view the current detailed configuration for `sda5`. And another example:

```
# cryptsetup status sda5_crypt
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt is active and is in use.
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
[...]
```

Read more on `dm-crypt` on [Wikipedia: dm-crypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt) and more on eCryptfs on [Wikipedia: eCryptfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecryptfs).

Comment: Thank you. Mine shows AES-XTS with a 512 bit key. Is that the default or does it vary by CPU?

Comment: Varies by Ubuntu default options in the installation I guess. This may have changed since 12.10 as I'm still on 12.04 and it was possible to select the cipher yourself in the 'alternate' installer, unavailable since 12.10.