# Can Windows 10 spy on your activity in Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

We all know W10 is spyware disguised as an operating system, but in the absence of W7, it's all we have for games. My question is that if I dualboot Ubuntu with Win10, will its feely data-tentacles be safely cordoned away in its own partition?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu support venue, not a Windows complaint and rant venue. We would prefer that you avoid slandering other OS here.

Answer (score 3):

Windows cannot natively read Ubuntu's default ext4 filesystem format. Writing to an ext4 partition in Ubuntu from Windows is possible only if an [application to read/write ext4 partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows) is installed in Windows.

In the Ubuntu installer there is an *Encrypt the Ubuntu installation for security option* [which provides an additional level of security](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239579/laptop-hdd-encrypted-with-lvm-full-disk-encryption).