# Is it possible to overwrite ubuntu from windows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I had Win10 on my SSD and installed Ubuntu afterwards. All I did was  insert an Ubuntu USB and partitioned the disk and installed.

In the meantime, I've read some articles about this and and a few stipulated that *I need to partition my disk **in Windows first***.

Everything is running as expected, but I'm not sure if there is an issue that can occur (e.g. windows does not know that there is Ubuntu and it could use this space)?

*Is there a way to fix this?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Windows 10 spy on your activity in Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078440/can-windows-10-spy-on-your-activity-in-linux) and [How do I remove my Ubuntu partition from Windows 7 and reuse the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138250/how-do-i-remove-my-ubuntu-partition-from-windows-7-and-reuse-the-space)

Comment: @karel as you need 2 duplicates to solve this one single question, **I disagree with the duplicate** and have formulated an answer instead...  **;-) 0:-)**

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Of course all things are possible including doing something ill-advised with Windows to the disk space that Ubuntu resides on, however it doesn't sound like you have anything you need to fix. My best advice is don't fix it, it's not broken.

Comment: I think it is recommended to shrink your Windows partition from within Windows first, although the Ubuntu installer seems to be able to handle that itself. Shrinking a partition may lead to file-system corruption in some cases, If your NTFS file-system is corrupted, you can repair it only with Windows tools. It is also recommended to defragment a NTFS-formatted partition and run chkdsk before shrinking a NTFS-partition. As everything works as expected for you, you are good to go, nothing to fix.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is running as expected: **no, you do not need to repartition the disk** from Windows first: Ubuntu is quite capable of reading [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) partitions.

Windows however does not know anything about [EXT4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) partitions so *it will not use them* and display them as "unknown" and *as long as you don't delete them from the Windows disk management utility* there is no risk neither.

#### Happy Ubuntu computing!  ;-)