# Is there any way to format my hard drive so that data cannot be restored?

Tags: security, hard-drive, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I securely erase a USB hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-usb-hard-drive)
>   [How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner)

I have 500 GB HD and I have very important personal data in it. The thing is that if I format my hard drive and sell my PC, there is a chance that someone will reformat it and restore all data in it. So is there any way no one can restore my data after I format it?

Comment: This answer is about **whole drives**, not a **single file**. It's a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/17640/6969. @TomBrossman Be sure to remove the keyslots in the beginning of partitions when trying to clear encrypted disks. For SSD it becomes more difficult due to wear levelling.