# How to completely erase hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, format, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I securely erase a USB hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-usb-hard-drive)
>   [How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner)

I am looking for software/script/whatever that can completely destroy data on hard drive. By destroy I mean beyond recovery(even with special software). Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-usb-hard-drive

Answer (score 5):

The tool named wipe deletes data permanently on HDD. To install it using terminal

```
sudo apt-get install wipe
```

To wipe out all data within a whole HDD type in terminal.

```
sudo wipe /dev/sdaX
```

where X is your partition.

Comment: Do I have to use wipe from live-cd to format my main hard-drive where my OS is installed?

Comment: How do I figure out my Partition?

Answer (score 5):

Would this be something you'd be looking for?

```
sudo -i
shred -f -n 5 -z [Location of drive]
```

If you want to make shred do more distortion-application, then bring up shred's help:

```
shred --help
```

or

```
man shred
```

Comment: Do I have to use shred from live-cd to format my main hard-drive where my OS is installed?

Comment: That would be best, since if you're running off a dual-boot, you would shred the "disk" file that Ubuntu is running from.

Answer (score 4):

DBAN http://www.dban.org/ is commonly used for that purpose, it is an iso image which you burn to a CD (or other media), boot, and write random data over the disk multiple times (depending on settings).

Somewhat similar to something like

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=#disk path#
```

Though I presume DBAN might have more options and a nicer interface

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/DRIVEDEVICE` is faster.