# How can I quickly wipe everything and do a clean install

Tags: delete, dell-mini-9

I have a Minidell with SSD from 2009. I'd like to do a quick wipe everything and clean install to give it away. What is the fastest way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely erase hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206773/how-to-completely-erase-hard-drive) and [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo dd if="/dev/zero" of="/dev/sdX" bs=4M count=32
```

Should do the trick. (`X` being the block device of your SSD)

---

After wiping, I suggest you install Ubuntu in OEM mode so that the end user is able to create their own user account and such.

Comment: Hmm, I did that and it probably answers the first question. Now how do I do a clean install? My screen says: error: unknown filesystem. Entering rescue mode. grub rescue>. Should I install Ubuntu or Lubuntu, or an older version of Ubuntu? The netbook has 2GB Ram, Atom processor and 16GB of memory

Comment: @ThierryMsika - You'll need to burn an Ubuntu ISO to a DVD or a USB drive, and then boot from that media and install. Again, I suggest installing in OEM mode.

Comment: How can I get to the booting order screen now?

Comment: @ThierryMsika - Well, that depends on the specific computer you have. There is a certain key you can hold down during boot that will take you to the BIOS

Comment: @ThierryMsika Regarding which version to install, either Xubuntu or Lubuntu would be my recommendation.

Comment: It's a Minidell. I have tried a few keys but only get back to  grub rescue>

Comment: @ThierryMsika Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62593/discussion-between-android-dev-and-thierry-msika).

Comment: I have quite literally laughed out loud. My answer is deleted. Why do people take these things so god damn seriously, I was only engaging in the discussion. Ubuntu used to be so much fun, what happened !

Comment: @hatterman - You might consider posting on Meta about it

Comment: I have no desire to, I have more enjoyable things to do to be completely honest. Perhaps it was a tad unprofessional of me to vent .... however my point still stands. I was simply engaging in the discussion.

Comment: @hatterman This is a Q&A, not a forum.

Comment: Indeed, hence I answered the question.