# How to clear all files in a folder ending with `.log`?

Tags: 18.04, files, delete

I have log files in a folder. These files after some size are creating a new file `old_name.log1` and writing to it.

Now there are many files and I can't clear them one by one. I want to delete `old_name.log1`, `old_name.log2` etc and clear `old_name.log`.

The file_name can be anything. But the file ends with `.log` and it's extended files ends with `.log1`, `.log2`, etc. How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete .log1, .log2, etc. files:

```
rm *.log[1-9]*
```

- `rm` - Delete files
- `*.log[1-9]*` - All files in the current directory that contain `.log` followed by a digit 1-9 then anything else

To test the command before running it, replace the `rm` with `echo`. It will print the matching files.

To truncate .log files:

```
echo -n | tee *.log
```

- `echo -n` - Print nothing
- `tee *.log` - Write from stdin to all .log files in the current directory

Comment: How to clear these files using the command line? I know how to find. To clear a single file I would use `> old_name.log` But I want to clear multiple files instead of typing each one of their names.

Comment: @Shameless Oh, I thought "clear" meant "delete". Usually I've heard emptying a file called "erasing" or maybe "zeroing" or "wiping". I'll revise the answer to do that.

Comment: @wjandrea this won't work right. Your rm code won't delete log files named *.log.01, *.log.02, etc. Your tee code won't get ANY log files with any names like *.log.1, *.log.01, etc. And, you don't want to touch any *.log file, as it's probably an open active file.

Comment: @heynnema You're totally right. My answer is meant to answer the question exactly as asked, regardless of effects. I don't know enough about log files to really comment on it anyway.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89457/discussion-on-answer-by-wjandrea-how-to-clear-all-files-in-a-folder-ending-with).

Answer (score 6):

Note that OP apparently wants to truncate files. In such case, the desired command is

```
find /path/to/dir -regextype sed -regex ".*\.log[1-9]*" -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Alternatively, in `bash`

```
shopt -s globstar
truncate -s 0 **/*.log[1-9]
```

---

If you want to clear out any file that has `.log` in the name

```
find /path/to/dir -name "*.log*"
```

If you target `.log[digit]` specifically, use

```
find /path/to/dir -regextype sed -regex ".*\.log[1-9]*"
```

Once you verify either of these two commands find the files you want, append `-delete` to the command for actual removal

Comment: How to clear these files using the command line? I know how to find. To clear a single file I would use `> old_name.log` But I want to clear multiple files instead of typing each one of their names.

Comment: @Shameless  Please read the last sentence in my answer. `find` with `-delete` option does exactly what you ask. Full command is `find /path/to/dir -regextype sed -regex ".*\.log[1-9]*" -delete` .  It's common practice to first list files, then delete them to avoid unintended errors.

Comment: @Shameless If by clear you mean "keep filename, but delete contents", then you want `find /path/to/dir -regextype sed -regex ".*\.log[1-9]*" -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;`

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty... assuming that you have permissions for these log files and directory itself... and you wish to **delete** the .log* files...

1. in a `Files` window, open the directory where the log files are located
2. search for **.log** files
3. `Select All`, control-click any files to **exclude** (like the active and open *.log)
4. then `Move to Trash`

**Note**: if you wish to "clear" the .log file, close the application that makes the current .log file, then delete the current .log file with `Move to Trash`, and then right-click in the folder, select `New Document`, then `Blank Document`, and `Rename...` using the correct .log filename.

Comment: Well Done! Everyone thinks command line is the only tool for Linux, but GUI indeed works too!