# Can I securely erase a hard drive by running `wipe` against `/dev/sdb`?

Tags: hard-drive

I was looking for a comparatively fast way to securely delete a hard drive I intend to sell and I found this in a German Ubuntu wiki:

```
wipe -q -Q 1 -R /dev/zero -S r -r $PATH
```

It said that according to contemporary research this would suffice. Is that true? Because it was done in one second:

```
arno@arno-X55A:~$ sudo wipe -q -Q 1 -R /dev/zero -S r -r /dev/sdb
Okay to WIPE 1 special file ? (Yes/No) Yes
Renaming                         /dev/sdb ->                         /dev/u8jSynOperation finished.
0 files wiped and 1 special file ignored in 0 directories, 0 symlinks removed but not followed, 0 errors occured.
```

Using the standard wipe command resulted in an ETA of 2 years for my 2 tb hdd.

Comment: The `-Q 1` tells it to do 1 pass. Default is 4 and more passes is better ;) If you drop the `-q` too it should do 34 passes (8 of those are random).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive

Comment: The guy in the post says it took him 20min for a 4 gb drive using shred. That would be 167 HOURS for me 2 tb drive. That is a little to long... The point here is to find a comparatively quick solution for large drives.

Comment: shred is not the one you want (you can recover from shred if I read the bottom answer correctly). see the wipe answer. That should do it (not slow either though but the amount of passes is crucial. Try with 2, 4, 8 and see how long it takes) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the output of the command you ran, you can see that the `wipe` command did not in fact do anything, it ignored the hard disk:

> ```
> 0 files wiped and 1 special file ignored in 0 directories, 0 symlinks removed but not followed, 0 errors occured.
> ```

The [man page for wipe](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/any/en/man1/wipe.1.html) indicates that this is the way to delete entire disks by specifying a special file:

```
wipe -kqD /dev/sdb
```

`-k` indicates that the file `/dev/sdb` should be kept and that wipe shouldn't attempt to delete it. `-q` means that wipe will make four passes (considered quick). `-D` means follow symlinks if `/dev/sdb` happens to be a symlink.

You can add the other options mentioned in your question, but I think `-k` would be essential for a special file.

If that still doesn't work, have a look at this question for other methods: [How can I securely erase a hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive)

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me what a symlink is?

Comment: OK it's been running a few hours and I have an ETA of 11 weeks. There must be something quicker. There wasn't any sensitive data on the device. I just don't want some curious user to dig up anything that doesn't concern him. It doesn't have to stand up to a forensic lab. Isn't there anything quicker? And please rename the title to "quick way of securely erasing large drives" or something.

Comment: @Arno: then open pass should be sufficient: `wipe -kD -Q 1 /dev/sdb`. If you don't care about security at all, you can delete all the partitions using a tool like Gparted, which will take less than a minute.