# Make it so files can't be recovered

Tags: data-recovery, permanent-delete

I have a laptop with 1 TB hdd which I am selling. My laptop has contained many sensitive data over the years and I wanted to remove any chances of ever recovering that data. I have planned on using the command `sfill` of package `secure-delete`.

> Note: I want to keep the OS intact and only clean out the free space

The problem is that it could take too much time doing the erase, so I wanted to know the best option to use with `sfill` or any other program which I can use to do the same.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/359540/securely-erase-hard-drive-using-the-disk-utility  or  http://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive

Comment: so `head -c 32 /dev/urandom | openssl enc -rc4 -nosalt -in /dev/zero -pass stdin | dd of=/dev/sda bs=1M` will not remove any of my current files but clear all the free space right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to keep the OS intact and only clean out the free space

No, you don't. Not only is that far more likely that you'll have missed something, it's bucketloads more *manual* work for you checking every nook and cranny.

Nuke the disk from orbit in a filesystem-agnostic way (per Rinwind's comment: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive)) from a Live CD. The wipe is going to take time. It has to write to every sector on the disk. A few extra GB for the installation won't make much of a difference. Set it off and leave it going overnight.

Then just [do an OEM install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview). This will allow the new owner to select their username and computer name. An OEM install takes under 20 minutes from a USB stick.