# Is there a way for me to uninstall or delete EVERYTHING off of my computer?

Tags: uninstall, delete

Is there a way for me to uninstall or delete EVERYTHING off of my computer including Linux Ubuntu because I want to make sure I can know everything that I have on it is just the stuff that I need.
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: If your computer is a laptop and it has a recovery partition, you probably don't want to delete the recovery partition.

Comment: ok but every thing else  is ok to be deleted

Comment: dd, scrub, http://askubuntu.com/questions/359540/securely-erase-hard-drive-using-the-disk-utility

Comment: i wil check if it is than i am sorry for waesting your time with this

Comment: Have you tried rm -rfv *

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

Download the Ubuntu Trusty Tahr mini.iso:

32 bits, 4 gb of RAM or less:

[Here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

64 bits, More than 4 Gb of RAM:

[Here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

Copy it to /mnt

Edit the file /etc/grub.d/40_custom

End of file add these lines

```
menuentry "Ubuntu Netinstall" {
set isofile="/mnt/mini.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
linux (loop)/linux 
initrd (loop)/initrd.gz
}
```

*Change at appropriate /, (hd0,1) it is /dev/sda1, (hd0,2) is /dev/sda2, (hd1,1) is /dev/sdb1*

Run in a terminal

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the `Shift key`, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with `Ubuntu Netinstall`

Boot your computer from the the mini.iso and select `Install`

You can then follow the instructions from the text-based installer.

With manual partitioning you can delete and create partitions except /, **that can only be overwritten**.

Answer (score -1):

Burn a Ubuntu live cd. Start it and click "Try Ubuntu" then start gparted and delete every partition or create a new partition table.

Comment: That will NOT delete data, you need to over write the data not just partition.

Comment: Well is there any way to do it with no other recourses than the computer because i do not realy want to burne a disk or any thing else?

Comment: @BlastCloud I don't know how to do it in anoter way but you can also make a bootable usb stick.