# How do I render Ubuntu unusable by deleting the full disk encryption key?

Tags: encryption, luks

I have an old computer that I'm ready to get rid of that has been encrypted using LUKS full disk encryption. Is it possible to delete the encryption key from the LUKS metadata so that nobody will ever be able to unlock the partition again? If so, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: You could boot from a USB (Live CD) and run `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda bs=1M` or something similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Securely erase hard drive using the Disk Utility](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359540/securely-erase-hard-drive-using-the-disk-utility)

Comment: *If* the passphrase is secure then so is the data... but that doesn't prevent guessing it, so changing & wiping is a good idea (sounds almost  like a punchline ;-)

Comment: @CharlesGreen overwriting the whole drive is way overkill for LUKS, I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just overwriting the LUKS header will work, overwriting the whole drive is way overkill for LUKS & would take possibly hours longer.

The LUKS header could be 1MB or 2MB or bigger  depending on the type & number of keys, [ArchWiki advises](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Drive_Preparation) to wipe/overwrite the first 10MB:

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdx2 bs=512 count=20480`

Note the correct partition sdx2 or whatever it is, you can check with a live dvd/usb and `lsblk` or `blkid` and confirm with the `cryptsetup` command below, this will tell you if partition sdx5 for example is a LUKS device:

`cryptsetup -v isLuks /dev/sdx5`

Also from ArchWiki:

> **Note:** It is crucial to write to the LUKS encrypted partition ( /dev/sdx5 in this example)
>   and not directly to the disks device node. If you did set up encryption as a device-mapper
>   layer on top of others, e.g. LVM on LUKS on RAID then write to RAID respectively.

You could only (or additionally) delete all the luks keyslots, leaving no keys, if you know a working passphrase. See `man cryptsetup` or a [web version here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup), with:

`cryptsetup -v luksRemoveKey  <device>`

or

`cryptsetup -v luksKillSlot <device> <key slot number>`

Also note about SSDs (also from ArchWiki):

> When wiping the header with random data everything left on the device is encrypted data.
>   An exception to this may occur for an SSD, because of cache blocks SSDs employ. In theory
>   it may happen that the header was cached in these some time before and that copy may
>   consequently be still available after wiping the original header. For strong security
>   concerns, a secure ATA erase of the SSD should be done (procedure please see the
>   [cryptsetup FAQ 5.19](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#5-security-aspects) ).