# How do I format my computer to be unrecoverable?

Tags: data-recovery, 19.04, format

I have a 500Gb HDD hard disk in my Laptop, and I want to sell it, so I am asking if I can format it such that no one can recover my old  data, and if yes, How can I do that? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you choose "slow" format this resets all of the bits to 0. It's impossible to recover the data from there.

Comment: @tatsu Thank you sir, can i do it when i boot by usb?

Comment: yes you can install dd and gparted is already install on the liveUSB this answer will probably proove quite useful to you :  https://askubuntu.com/a/359547/307184

Answer (score 1):

You can securely delete all the files with a program like shred
It overwrites the files before deleting them, so that a recovery wont get success

You can also overwrite all the HDD and, then, format it

See shred program : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/shred.1.html

Or overwrite with `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX bs=4096 status=progress` then format the drive