# Best way to wipe HDD with multiple partitions and format into NTFS

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, format

My laptop had a hardware issue while under warranty so I received a new laptop and am sending my old laptop and hard drive back. I want to wipe all data off of all partitions of my HDD, and send it back as a single blank NTFS partition.

I know Google returns many ways to format the hard drive, but I'm not sure which way is best for my scenario. I mainly used the laptop for school assignments and browsing so there's no sensitive data on it. Which way is best for what I want to do?

I already have a Ubuntu 14.04 live USB

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner or http://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive - the `dd` command is included on any live session (don't wipe your USB drive!). There should not be the need of formatting to NTFS after that but you can using gparted.

Comment: "there's no sensitive data on it".  Then don't waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

Search for `Disks` in Ubuntu Dash, it does the job pretty good.

Connect and unmount the HDD you want to delete, delete it (multiple places to open menu in `Disks`) then create a new NTFS Partition. Tick the option:

`Contents -> Erase -> Overwrite existing data with zeros (slow)`

Voila, wait couple of hours and your HDD is clean =D

EDIT: I just tried to unswap the SWAP, placed few files on new partition, deleted the same partiton with `Disks` and tried to recover with TestDisk. No results.