# ubuntu install to erase harddrive

Tags: asus, secure-erase

I bought used Asus Eee 1101HAB on Ebay running Windows XP and want to erase everything from the previous owner and run Ubuntu. Can i install Ubuntu in a way that will erase or wipe the hard drive in the same way that DBAN would?

Comment: Sure, erasing everything is one of the very first options. Ubuntu may be to much for an old netbook, try [ubuntu-mate](http://ubuntu-mate.org/) instead.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you are intending to install Ubuntu compare your [system specifications](https://www.cnet.com/products/asus-eee-pc-1101ha-seashell/specs/) to [Ubuntu system requirements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) to help you decide the best [Ubuntu flavour](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-flavours) for your system.

Answer (score 2):

DBAN has a number of erase options. A lot depends on whether you are concerned whether any of the original data would be recoverable. I'll consider this unlikely as it's not your data and since it was still on the system when you purchased it I would think it unlikely that the seller was concerned about it either. The installation process offers to erase the drive and install Ubuntu as noted by [mikewhatever in his comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910280/ubuntu-install-to-erase-harddrive#comment1431407_910280) This should be sufficient in your case. However if you feel the need to perform a secure erase on the drive this can be managed via the live media Ubuntu installer via the Try Ubuntu option and one of the [numerous methods described here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive) My personal preference is `dd` (nicknamed [disk destroyer](https://askubuntu.com/a/17642/225694) due to it's unforgiving nature when people choose the wrong device to wipe.) Another good choice is to use the built-in [secure erase](https://askubuntu.com/a/860658/225694) feature of the drive itself.