# How to erase one partition not all of the disk in a safe way on ubuntu

Tags: disk, format

[image: Installation type window Ubuntu]

I have 2 partitions, my system file, swap.. every thing is on the partition which named now (free space) because I clicked the [-] button.
The second partition is the partition where I usually store some important data in and I don't want to erase it.

What I want to do is to Erase the partition which called (free space) safely, mean if someone installed photoRec for example he will not be able to recover my old files.
I found here on this website many answers, but all of what I found guides the user to erase all of his disk; but I don't want to do that, I just want to erase one partition, because the secret data is stored there (in free space).
I don't know what is the name of this method, maybe it's replacing the free data on the partition with zeros, (I don't know but want the safest).
Another question: the hacker can't recover the files on my partition (free space) after erasing it safely even if the another partition (/dev/sda4 ntfs) is still on my device without erasing, true?

Comment: The free space is not allocated to a partition; I see only a single partition being sda4 (ntfs).   Free space is unallocated to any partition; dev sda is the physical disk itself (not a partition). I'm confused by what you see as the 'second' partition as I only see one (sda4)

Comment: Me too, I don't know any thing, the only thing I know that my linux was on that free space before I clicked the [-] button.

Comment: Use the space for something else (ie. make a partition there, and fill it with junk, or write 0101010 etc. on it, then something else or 1010101, then erase the partition so it' free again) - i'm still confused by your question though.

Comment: Maybe the question should be: I want to make safe erase for this (free space) not for the /dev/sda4 ntfs.

Comment: Thank you because you're trying to help me guiverc, okay I made a partition there, but this is a very big space 262GB how I'll fill all of this free space? What is the best way?

Comment: I would `dd` data to it.   (/dev/random)  but I'll mark it duplicate which will provide links

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive  (how can I securely erase a hard drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free space shown in the picture is an unpartitioned portion of the disk.
To securely erase it:
1 - Create a partition on free space and format it ext4
2 - Write randoms on all space
3 - Delete created partition

---

Here is more details for step 2 : how to write randoms on all the free space
Let's say that the partition created from free space is `/dev/sda1`

**Option 0** : not randoms but fill with zeros
The Ubuntu `gnome-disks` manager have an 'Erase' option which fill with zeros
Its quite secure but there is more secure : filling with randoms

**Option 1** : Fill with randoms using **dd**:
`sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1`

**Option 2** : Fill with randoms using the secure deletion tool [**shred**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_%28Unix%29)
If not present on the system, install it, its part of the package coreutils
`sudo apt install coreutils`
Usage:
`sudo shred -v -n 1 /dev/sda1`
`option -n 1` is for 1 pass, can be increased for more security and longer process time...

Comment: The "format it ext4" part of step 1 is not needed here: It is sufficient to create an unformatted partition to apply any of the options described here.