# How to securely wipe my SSD before reinstalling an encrypted Ubuntu?

Tags: ssd, samsung, secure-erase

I think I didn't encrypt my drive when I installed Ubuntu and I would like to use the opportunity to change that when I install Ubuntu 20.04. I'd like to make sure that all data is permanently wiped before I do a fresh installation, but that's turning out to be a bit of a problem. All I found online on the topic was the advice to go on the manufacturer's website to see how to proceed.

I have a Samsung 970 EVO SSD, and the tool that Samsung offers (Samung Magician) appears to be available exclusively for Windows. Any ideas how to get this done?

Comment: Look up how to run `dd` to zero out a drive. Any Search Engine will happily give you easy instructions. Warning: It will wipe your drive of all data without any hope of recovery no matter how remorseful you are in the future. Do not make a typo, or you'll be sorry.

Comment: I second the other users suggestion of using `dd`

Comment: shred, wipe, dd ... https://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-hard-drive

Comment: @cmak.fr the shred command shouldn't be used on SSDs though. It looks my best bet is `hdparm`

Comment: @cmak.fr this only reduces the lifecycle  and potentially damages your hardware

Comment: Why bother deleting old data? Wont the encryption process overwrite it anyway? And why this obsession with encryption? Are you afraid that someone steals your disks?

Comment: @all : you're right: secure erasing requires writing all the disk space, which reduces disk life although ssd's are improving on this point

Answer (score 1):

[Use the secure erase feature](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Perform_a_SSD_Secure_Erase) since there might be spare sectors etc. so just overwriting 3 times is maybe not enough

[Archwiki also has a good feature on that](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive/Memory_cell_clearing)